# Redirecting users to login page outside an iframe

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I have a project in PHP that uses multiple tabs on a single page, implementing the plugin found on this page: http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdScrollTab/sample.htm

I require various users to log in to the system. I've implemented a server-side check within each tab's iframe to see if a certain session variable is set. If the variable is not set, I redirect the user to the login page, which is external to the set of tabs. This is to prevent a user from opening an iframe in a separate window, without having the necessary session variables set.

However, if the session expires and the tabs are still open, the user is directed to the login page within the tab. This is undesirable, because the entire set of tabs will open within the particular tab after logging in.

I want to redirect the user to the login page outside the set of jQuery tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting the following javascript snip in your login page.

```
if(top!=self){
   top.location.replace(document.location);
}
```

Comment: The JavaScript snippet hated most by every affiliate marketers.